# Pymongo script thread safe

Tags: thread-safety, pymongo

I have a pymongo script which checks for an element, if it is in the collection then returns it's id otherwise it inserts and then return the id of the newly inserted collection. I want this to be thread safe. Because several scripts may use this script to check for the element. 
How should I make this thread safe.

I saw start_request method, thought it will work but it doesn't. It inserts two documents referring to the same element.

Comment: from the fact you're using the word `scripts` and don't mention `threads`, I suspect it isn't thread-safety you're after...

Answer (score 0):

As `shx2` mentioned, you are not looking for thread safety, but for atomic database transactions.

MongoDB [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify) might be what you are looking for. It atomically updates the document, or inserts it if you specify the `new: true` and `upsert: true` options and returns the document.